# How to add gtilde and Gtilde to my customized keyboard on Ubuntu 18.04? Some keysyms don't work

Tags: special-characters, custom-keyboard

I'm trying to customize my keyboard in order to be able to write some extra characters with tilde, which I need to write in my language. I would like to be able to press AltGr + g (for gtilde) and AltGr + Shift + g (for Gtilde). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and have already tried the following:

1. dead_tilde doesn't work with consonants.
2. It is not possible to use two Unicode codes for a key (g with tilde with a combining diacritical mark), U+0067 U+0303 (for gtilde) and U+0047 U+0303  (for Gtilde).
3. I managed to add tilde to all vowels (ã, ẽ, ĩ, õ, ũ, ỹ), but can't get the g with tilde. In theory, there is a List of keysyms recognised by Xmodmap here:

http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/List_of_Keysyms_Recognised_by_Xmodmap

But the key codes: 0x16e3 (for gtilde) and 0x16d3 (for Gtilde) don't work. I don't know why.

Could someone please help me to add g̃ and G̃ to my keyboard?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is hacky and I don't like it, but one thing you could do is redefine a rarely used keysym to be the gtilde, and then put that in your keymap, as described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43073/custom-xkb-layout-in-which-one-key-creates-two-unicode-code-points

Quoting the answer here, modified for the gtilde case:

> Testing shows that the keymap will ONLY take a single key in each
> position.
>
> BUT, if you use a rare/never used keysym in the keymap definition,
> then a global Xmodmap to make THAT keysym output the various unicode
> characters you need, this'll work.
>
> #### In the keymap:
>
> ```
> key <AC05> { [ g, G, XF86LaunchA, XF86LaunchB ] };
> ```
>
> #### In a global Xmodmap: (perhaps loaded from /etc/profile.d ?)
>
> ```
> keysym XF86LaunchA = U0067 U0303
> keysym XF86LaunchB = U0047 U0303
> ```
>
> There are quite a few unused/special-use keysyms, I chose the
> LaunchA/B as an example.

I'm still looking for a more maintainable solution to the same problem, see my question here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599684/why-cant-i-type-a-g%cc%83